# Returning generic arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I am having problems at the moment of initialize the array and returning it. The method is suppose to return common items of a generic array, but i cant initialize array "a" or returning it. Any advice??

```
public static <T> T[] commonItems( T[] arr1, T[] arr2)
{
    T[] a;
    int pos = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++)
        {
           if(arr1[i].equals(arr2[j]))
           {
               a[pos] = arr1[i];
               pos++;
           }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: You will probably need to pass the class type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java

Comment: have a look here maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java?rq=1

Comment: thenk you that helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

You don't know in advance how many elements are common, so in the first step it is best to collect the common items in a list:

```
public static <T> T[] commonItems( T[] arr1, T[] arr2)
{
     ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
     for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
     {
          for( int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++)
          {
              if (arr1[i].equals(arr2[j]))
                  list.add(arr1[i]);
          }
     }
```

Then you can create the result array, using `Class.getComponentType`:

```
     T[] result = (T[])Array.newInstance(arr1.getClass().getComponentType(), list.size());
     list.toArray(result);
     return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you recommendations and advises, it really helped.

Comment: @newacct not clear to me what you mean. How do you call `commonItems` passing a `String[]` and `Integer[]` array?

Comment: @newacct you can call `commonItem(stringarray, integerarray);` and it will compile (`T` is `Object&Comparable&Serializable`). It will not exactly fail but return an empty string array. But if you write `String[] s = commonItem(stringarray, integerarray)` it will not compile: So I don't exactly get your point.